# Мини-поиск по массиву с выводом найденной информации

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, события, search

Почему-то выдается ошибка, если добавить не только поиск по имени, но и по возрасту, хоть алгоритм совершенно одинаков.

```js
    const data = [
        {name: 'Katya', years: 16,},
        {name: 'Nastya', years: 19},
        {name: 'Kristina', years: 20,},
    ];
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    let div = document.getElementById('inf');
    let search = document.getElementById('search');
    let result;
    let yearResult;
    let matchElem;

    function match(arr, sign){
        matchElem = data.filter(item => {
            return item[sign].includes(input.value)
        });
        arr = matchElem;
        if (input.value === '') {
            div.innerHTML = '';
        } else {
            arr.forEach(function (item, i, result) {
                div.innerHTML = '';
                div.innerHTML += '<p>' + result[i]['name'] + '  ' + result[i]['years'] + '</p>';
            });
        }
    }

    search.addEventListener('click', function () {
        result = null;
        yearResult = null;
        match(result, 'name');
        match(yearResult, 'years');
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="search">Найти</button>
<div id="inf"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас разные данные, перевидите их в строку `toString()` и для поиска желательно еще `toLowerCase()`

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Katya',
    years: 16,
  },
  {
    name: 'Nastya',
    years: 19
  },
  {
    name: 'Kristina',
    years: 20,
  },
];
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let div = document.getElementById('inf');
let search = document.getElementById('search');
let result;
let yearResult;
let matchElem;

function match(arr, sign) {
  matchElem = data.filter(item => {
    return item[sign].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.value.toLowerCase()) != -1
  });
  arr = matchElem;
  if (input.value === '') {
    div.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    arr.forEach(function(item, i, result) {
      div.innerHTML = '';
      div.innerHTML += '<p>' + result[i]['name'] + '  ' + result[i]['years'] + '</p>';
    });
  }
}

search.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result = null;
  yearResult = null;
  match(result, 'name');
  match(yearResult, 'years');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="search">Найти</button>
<div id="inf"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том, что вы используете метод `includes` для числа, а в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) написано, что этот метод работает только для строк.

Оберните в числа в кавычки `16 => '16'` и ваш пример заработает для поиска по возрасту.

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Katya',
    years: '16',
  },
  {
    name: 'Nastya',
    years: '19',
  },
  {
    name: 'Kristina',
    years: '20',
  },
];
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let div = document.getElementById('inf');
let search = document.getElementById('search');
let result;
let yearResult;
let matchElem;

function match(arr, sign) {
  matchElem = data.filter(item => {
    return item[sign].includes(input.value)
  });
  arr = matchElem;
  if (input.value === '') {
    div.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    arr.forEach(function(item, i, result) {
      div.innerHTML = '';
      div.innerHTML += '<p>' + result[i]['name'] + '  ' + result[i]['years'] + '</p>';
    });
  }
}

search.addEventListener('click', function() {
  result = null;
  yearResult = null;
  match(result, 'name');
  match(yearResult, 'years');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="search">Найти</button>
<div id="inf"></div>
```